# MAPIInitialize without error message boxes

Tags: windows, winapi, outlook, mapi

A 64-bit copy of Outlook is installed, and a 32-bit program is trying to call MAPIInitialize(). It will fail, which is OK, but it will also display a modal message box and block until the message box is dismissed.

[image: MAPIInitialize error message]

How can I prevent the very unhelpful message box from appearing?

(In case it matters, I'm linking to mapi32.lib and calling it from a C++ program. The OS is Windows 7.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code ends up calling a stub 32 bit dll.
Are you statically linking to mapi32.dll? You need to load the right dll from the Program Files folder. LoadLibrary() will return 0 and GetLastError will be ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT if the bitness of the dll does not match the bitness of your process.

Comment: Thanks, it works. And the path to the right DLL can be obtained using a slight modification of this code - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb820994.aspx .